# C# how do i access a variable in another class?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, member

This gets me the name of the class ("SolarPanel") but I want to get the value of the variable called "Name" (the one on line 30)

[image]

Comment: Why `SolarPanel.Name` doesnt work ?

Comment: ``this.GetType().Name`` gives you the name of the class, not the constant ``Name`` you created

Comment: I can't use SolarPanel.Name, i have more classes there, i want it to be dynamic.
One more thing. I create objects of type "SolarPanel", "Headquaters", etc - not objects of "Buildings" type. I hope this information helps

Comment: It is practically impossiible to access variables defined in nested scope.

Comment: @General-Doomer It isn't, but I agree this is a pain to work with

Comment: @FaraNume then create an `interface IName { string Name {get;}}`

Answer (score 2):

Define virtual property like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// name: Building
/// </summary>
public class Building
{
    /// <summary>
    /// name of building
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            // default name is class name with spaces between upper letters
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            bool wasUpper = false;
            foreach (char c in this.GetType().Name)
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    if (!wasUpper)
                    {
                        sb.Append(' ');
                        wasUpper = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    wasUpper = false;
                }
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            return sb.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }

    public void Construct()
    {
        string buildingName = this.Name;
        // do some work
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// name: Missile Station
/// </summary>
public class MissileStation : Building { }

/// <summary>
/// name: Radar Station "Buk"
/// </summary>
public class RadarBuk : Building
{
    /// <summary>
    /// overriden building name
    /// </summary>
    public override string Name { get { return @"Radar Station ""Buk"""; } }
}
```

Comment: This is the only really sensible way to achieve what the question asks

Comment: @MarkPim how about my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do up-casting which is bad thing (because there can be other descendants from Buildings class that have no such field). So, to play safe you have two options:

- Move the field to the parent class (i.e. Buildings)
- Override Construct() method as virtual one so descendants can alter the behavior and access their own fields

Comment: How can i move the field to the parent class without exposing myself to easy mistakes by storing each building name?
As for the second idea, i don't know how to do any of that :(

Comment: About second idea: instead of raw code like "this.GetType().Name" you can introduce a method, let say GetBuildingName(). Mark it virtual and return empty string (or so) in scope of Buildings class. Then, in descendants you can override GetBuildingName() so in SolarPanel class this method can clearly return "this.Name".

Comment: You can even make it 'abstract' in the base Buildings class which means Buildings itself doesn't implement it, but all descendent classes do. This forces you to give a name to all building types you create. If you go down this route you also have to mark the 'Buildings' class itself as abstract.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're constucting an instance of one of your inherited classes and you don't know what the type will be on construction (so `SolarPanel.Name` isn't an option).

You can do:

```
this.getType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(this, null);
```

But if all your types don't have the `Name` property, you should null check `GetProperty` first:

```
var prop = this.getType().GetProperty("Name");
string name = "";

if (prop != null)
{
    name = prop.GetValue(this, null);
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't exist in productive code, I'd stick with ``virtual`` methods/properties or ``Attributes``

Answer (score 0):

I dont agree with your class structure, but i will try to answer your question:

try this:

```
(string)this.GetType().GetField("Name").GetValue(this);
```

Comment: For demonstration it is perfectly fine

Comment: @downvoter: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: name is a const field not a property

Comment: @General-Doomer, please tell me how else you would do it when using reflection like in this example?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that reflection is a very slow way to get at this information - if you end up constructing thousands of these buildings you're likely to get a significant performance problem. @General-Doomer's answer is a much better approach

Comment: @Nico, you are right, i've changed my code to accessing const fields instead of properties.

Comment: Reflection is your friend. Do not turn it into your enemy.

Comment: I have been trying to answer the OPs question, why am i getting downvoted? 
is OPs programming style horrible and wrong? yes, did i answer his specific question? yes. is my answer wrong or dangerous?
i dont think so.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @MarkPim Don't do premature optimization. I agree with you, though. If possible, **stay away** from reflection

Comment: @w33z33, this is because your answer is an immediate patch, not a permanent cure. Topic-starter going bad code design (as he seems to be a novice at OOP) and your answer is pushing him deeper to hell rather than giving a hand from heavens. (besides, I didn't downvote here)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with `Attributes`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class NameAttribute : Attribute {
    public readonly string Name;

    public NameAttribute(string name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public static class Extensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// If existant, returns the name tag for given object, else null
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetNameTag(this object instance) {
        return instance.GetType().GetNameTag();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If existant, returns the name tag for given type, else null
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetNameTag(this Type type) {
        object[] names = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NameAttribute), false);
        switch(names.Length) {
            case 0:
                return null;
            case 1:
                return ((NameAttribute)names[0]).Name;
            default:
                throw new FormatException();
        }
    }
}

[Name("Headquater")]
public class Headquater : Building {
    // ...
}

[Name("Solar Panel")]
public class Solarpanel : Building {
    // ...
}
```

Now, you can simply do:

```
object panel = new SolarPanel();
Console.WriteLine(panel.GetNameTag());
```

And:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(SolarPanel).GetNameTag());
```

Comment: It's good code, but Relection is too 'heavy' for this task. Use OOP where is possible.

Comment: I agree with you, but this is clean code from the view of design, except that the "Name" should be an id to be looked up in resource dictionary to be ready for i18n.